# Why is json.dumps() a must in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

(This is probably a dumb question, so please wear your stupidity shields!) I've been a PHP programmer and am now learning Python + Flask. I recently had to struggle a lot with posting data through AJAX and returning a response. Finally, the code that worked was:

```
@app.route('/save', methods=['POST'])
def save_subscriptions():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sites = request.form.get('selected')
        print(sites)
        sites = sites[0:-1]        
        g.cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET sites = %s WHERE email = %s', [sites, session.get('email')])
        g.db.commit()
        return json.dumps({'status': 'success'})
```

If I change `return json.dumps({'status': 'success'})` to `return 1` I get an Exception that `int is not callable`. First of all, I don't understand who is trying to call that `int` and why? Secondly, in PHP, it was frequently possible to just `echo 1;` and this would become the AJAX response. Why doesn't `return 1` work in Flask, then?

Comment: Please sanitize your SQL queries!

Comment: @WillSherwood Thanks! I was wondering yesterday what was the equivalent of PHP's prepared statements but didn't give it much thought as it is a personal project. I'll change this pronto!

Comment: @WillSherwood Hey, wait a minute! I look at http://bobby-tables.com/python.html and wondering whether my queries aren't already sanitized. What else do I need to to?

Comment: @dotslash nono, you are doing it correctly, since you parameterize queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logic behind what should be returned by Flask views [is described in the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#about-responses) in detail:

> The return value from a view function is automatically converted into
>   a response object for you. If the return value is a string it’s
>   converted into a response object with the string as response body, an
>   200 OK error code and a text/html mimetype. The logic that Flask
>   applies to converting return values into response objects is as
>   follows:
>
> - If a response object of the correct type is returned it’s directly
>     returned from the view.
> - If it’s a string, a response object is created
>     with that data and the default parameters.
> - If a tuple is returned the
>     items in the tuple can provide extra information. Such tuples have to
>     be in the form (response, status, headers) where at least one item has
>     to be in the tuple. The status value will override the status code and
>     headers can be a list or dictionary of additional header values.
> - If
>     none of that works, Flask will assume the return value is a valid WSGI
>     application and convert that into a response object.

In your case, integer `1` is returned - Flask applies the last rule and tries to convert it into a response object and fails. Internally, [`make_response()` method](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L1675) is called which, in case of an integer, would call [`force_type()` method](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/40f48729f877e4c5c7a6a8bae481570811b171c7/werkzeug/wrappers.py#L815) of a `werkzeug.Response` class which would eventually fail creating an instance of a `BaseResponse` class when trying to instantiate a WSGI app:

```
app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
```

where `app` in your case is integer `1`.

Comment: Ah, silly me! So all I had to do was `return "1"`. Thanks! Will accept this as my answer as soon the site allows me.

Comment: And thanks for the full explanation. Makes me see web frameworks in a totally different light. :-)