# Peewee Flask Trying to Return Data from a BooleanField

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

I'm trying to return the `confirmed` BooleanField of a user in the `UserTable` model (so I can deny access to some routes later) with this code:

**models.py**

```
class UserTable(UserMixin, Model):
    email = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField()
    confirmed = BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/isconfirmed/<email>')
def isconfirmed(email):
    return models.UserTable.get(models.UserTable.email == email).confirmed
```

When I try this however I receive: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`

I've tried accessing `email` and `password` with:

`return models.UserTable.get(models.UserTable.email == email).email` etc. and it works just fine. I don't understand why it can't return a True or False from a BooleanField???

I'm using Postgres as my database if that is of any relevance / help.

Any help is appreciated greatly!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is happening.

`models.UserTable.get(models.UserTable.email == email).confirmed` is a legitimate query and it returns a boolean - `True` or `False`.

Now, referring to the [view response type handling logic](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#about-responses):

> The return value from a view function is automatically converted into
>   a response object for you. If the return value is a string it’s
>   converted into a response object with the string as response body, an
>   200 OK error code and a text/html mimetype. The logic that Flask
>   applies to converting return values into response objects is as
>   follows:
>
> - If a response object of the correct type is returned it’s directly
>     returned from the view.
> - If it’s a string, a response object is created
>     with that data and the default parameters.
> - If a tuple is returned the
>     items in the tuple can provide extra information. Such tuples have to
>     be in the form (response, status, headers) where at least one item has
>     to be in the tuple. The status value will override the status code and
>     headers can be a list or dictionary of additional header values.
> - If
>     none of that works, Flask will assume the return value is a valid WSGI
>     application and convert that into a response object.

when `Flask` sees a boolean returned from a view, it tries to think about it as a WSGI application instance, but fails.

You have to force it to be a string, if `True` or `False` is what you want to return from the view:

```
@app.route('/isconfirmed/<email>')
def isconfirmed(email):
    return str(models.UserTable.get(models.UserTable.email == email).confirmed)
```

Also see a related issue resolved here:

- [Why is json.dumps() a must in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468308/why-is-json-dumps-a-must-in-flask)

Comment: Ah! I'm just learning Flask and was very hazy on this kind of theory. I'd tried before to use the query in an if statement and return True or False manually - not understanding I couldn't return a boolean - which is what really confused me. I'll definitely read up on this part of the documentation!